# Insert subscript value in sql server varchar column

Tags: c#, sql-server, subscript

I am having a table with 2 columns.

---

id: number,
name : varchar(50)

---

I want to insert oxygen (O2) value in name field, 2 as subscript.
when i am inserting, it is not able to save it as subscript value.

one solution is to change name's data type to nvarchar.
but i am looking for better solution, So that i do not need to change in table.

Comment: Unicode characters are stored in `nvarchar`, example : Symbols, Hindi, Chinese characters etc

Answer (score 0):

I think only ASCII and Extended ASCII are allowed in char/varchar field. 
But if you use nchar/nvarchar then you can use any characters.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to change the column into `nvarchar(50)`.

If you stick to `varchar(50)`, the underlying set of representable characters depends on your collation. In general by collation we mean the sort order, e.g. does `Ø` sort together with `O` or as a separate letter after `Z`, and is it earlier or later than `Å`. But the collation also correlates to the underlying character set (set of representable characters). Try the query:

```
select TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME,
    DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_SET_NAME,
    COLLATION_NAME, COLLATIONPROPERTY(COLLATION_NAME, 'CodePage') as CODE_PAGE
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where COLUMN_NAME = N'name'
```

and note the `CHARACTER_SET_NAME`, `COLLATION_NAME`, and `CODE_PAGE` for your column. What do you have?

I highly doubt it will be something which can represent `'O₂'` correctly.

---

You could choose some convention, for example using HTML-like constructs such as `'O<sub>2</sub>'`, or [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX)-like ones such as `'O_2'`.